# React 16.3 method getDerivedStateFromProps is making form un-editable

Tags: reactjs, redux, crud

I have a simple React Redux CRUD App which works fine when editing an entry with a form while using componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle method. Recently wanted to replace it with componentWillReceiveProps method, which worked ok, meaning the edit form did pull us the data from the post that needs to be edited, but now the form is uneditable. Cannot write anything into the form anymore. Here is the previous code that was working:

```
state = {
  id: '',
  title: '',
  body: '',
  errors: {},
};
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState) {
const { id, title, body } = nextProps.post;
console.log(`Next Props in Will Receive Props: ${nextProps.post.title}`);

this.setState({
  id,
  title,
  body,
});
```

}

This is the code I'm trying to replace the above code with:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
const { id, title, body } = nextProps.post;
if (nextProps.post !== prevState.post) {
  return {
    id,
    title,
    body,
  };
}

return null;
```

}

And here is the form code:

```
  render() {
const { id, title, body, errors } = this.state;

return (
  <div className="add-post-from-container animated slideInLeft pt-5">
    <div className="card mb-3">
      <div className="card-header text-danger">
        <strong>Edit Post</strong>
      </div>
      <div className="card-body">
        <h5>Article ID: {id}</h5>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <div className="">
            <InputGroup
              name="title"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter Post Title"
              value={title}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              error={errors.title}
            />

            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-12">
                <InputTextarea
                  name="body"
                  value={body}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  error={errors.body}
                  placeholder="Enter Content"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mx-auto">
              <input
                type="submit"
                className="form-control form-control-lg btn btn-light mt-2"
                value="Update Post"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Please help me understand where I'm going wrong here. I'm pretty new to React/Redux.

Comment: You cannot compare objects with `!=`, either `JSON.stringify` both objects or compare individual properties

Answer (score 1):

Thanx Sawan for your answer, but turns out getDerivedStateFromProps was not the method I needed to replace componentWillReceiveProps. What I needed was componentDidUpdate. Here is the new code I'm posting for other lost souls like me ... I'm leaving the code that was replaced commented out ... hope this helps someone:

```
export class EditPost extends Component {
 static propTypes = {
 post: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
 editPost: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
 getPost: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};



state = {
    id: '',
    title: '',
    body: '',
    errors: {},
  };
  // THE FOLLOWING WAS REPLACED
  // componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState) {
  //   const { id, title, body } = nextProps.post;
  //   console.log(`Next Props in Will Receive Props: ${nextProps.post.title}`);

  //   this.setState({
  //     id,
  //     title,
  //     body,
  //   });
  // }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    this.props.getPost(id);
  }

  // THE FOLLOWING WAS USED TO REPLACE THE ABOVE COMMENTED OUT CODE
  componentDidUpdate(props, state, snapshot) {
    if (this.props.post !== props.post) {
      this.setState(this.props.post);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was having the same problem. Been looking around for a few hours until this post. A year later and this post is still helping others. +1

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the getDerivedStateFromProps method code as shown below:

```
   static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
       const { id, title, body } = nextProps.post;
       if (JSON.stringify(nextProps.post) !== JSON.stringify(prevState.post)) {
          return {
              id,
              title,
              body,
          };
       }

    return null;
 }
```

Note: I think you are not saving post in state, so above code won't work. You need to store post in state.

Personally, I think if the post id is unique it's better to compare ids instead of whole object. Sample code is shown below:

```
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
     const { id, title, body } = nextProps.post;
     if (nextProps.post.id !== prevState.id) {
       return {
         id,
         title,
         body,
       };
     }

return null;
}
```